# How to avoid getting out of position when colliding with another GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity game I have some moving objects. There are some collectables ( triggers ) and whenever a moving object enters its trigger the collectable should

- Replace itself with a moving object
- Destroy itself

Unfortunately the current moving object collides with the new spawned moving object so it will be out of position ( very little ). I would like to avoid that, so one piece connects smoothly to the other one.

---

**For reproduction purposes:**

*Moving*

- Create a cube GameObject
- Add a Rigidbody component but disable the usage of gravity
- Attach the following script to it

.

```
public class MoveForwardBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward; // just for testing purposes
    }
}
```

- Make this GameObject a prefab

*Collectable*

- Create a cube GameObject
- Add a Rigidbody component but disable the usage of gravity
- Enable the collider trigger and modify the following values

[image]

- Attach the following script to it

.

```
public class Collectable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject movingPrefab;
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
        Instantiate(movingPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

- Assign the moving prefab to the script
- Make this GameObject a prefab

Now setup a sample scene like so

[image]

and start the game. After creating a new moving prefab you can see that the initial moving prefab is not in position anymore

[image]

I think this is because of the collision with the new instantiated prefab. Do you have any suggestions how to avoid this?

Comment: So why did you use a trigger collider? The Collectable should be created as a static collider (no rigidbody, not a trigger), using OnCollisionEnter instead of OnTriggerEnter. Then it can stop the Moving when it touches.

Comment: I wanted to use the trigger because the collectable should replace itself with a moving object instantly. When stopping the moving object the left one ( starting at 0, 0, 1) still moves ( as expected, all 3 of them should go on moving )

Comment: With all explanation effort.. is the question why gameobject with `RigidBody` components is moving? Is [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/prevent-rigidbodies-from-pushing-each-other.228870/) the same problem?